# How to turn off electricity in an area with an electrical fault?

Tags: emergency-20

The tips and tricks mention the possibility to turn off the electricity in an area where there's an electrical fault. This comes with the tradeoff of increased chaos and the option to turn it back on once the emergency is completed.

There are two types of electrical faults which are not distinguished in the hint. There's a broken transformer which ignites it's surrounding and damages personal. And there's the "sea of electricity" which has to be turned off by a mechanic (wrench task) before anyone can enter the area.

I've searched every button in the game and read the hint over and over again. I also searched on the map for an almost invisible point where I could send an electrician.

Either I'm misunderstanding this and the hint refers to the wrench task, but not transformer faults.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since January 2024 release, the electricity boxes have a highlight icon above them and it's possible for novices to turn off electricity intuitively.

I would have never found them without the icon, though.